Having trouble including a long link in the answer text
In the comments section, one of the users referenced:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20sin%284%2A%28x%2B1%29%29%2Fsin%28x%2B1%29%20%2B%20sin%284%2A%28x-1%29%29%2Fsin%28x-1%29

In the comments section it works fine.  However, when I try to reference the link in my main text for my article article answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4942293/what-is-the-maximum-of-frac-sinnxa-sinxa-frac-sinnx-a-s/4943709#4943709
the comment link is very badly formatted and I am not sure how to fix it.
Please help!

I think it is the same issue as in your previous question - combining HTML and Markdown.
Your post contained the following:
<h5>3. Example plots</h5>
In the comments section, there is a [link][3] to the (plot)[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20sin%284%2A%28x%2B1%29%29%2Fsin%28x%2B1%29%20%2B%20sin%284%2A%28x-1%29%29%2Fsin%28x-1%29] of 
$$
y=\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x+1\right)\right)}{x+1}+\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x-1\right)\right)}{x-1}
$$

3. Example plots
In the comments section, there is a [link][3] to the (plot)[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20sin%284%2A%28x%2B1%29%29%2Fsin%28x%2B1%29%20%2B%20sin%284%2A%28x-1%29%29%2Fsin%28x-1%29] of 
$$
y=\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x+1\right)\right)}{x+1}+\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x-1\right)\right)}{x-1}
$$
Obviously, one of the issues is using incorrect (text)[URL] instead of the correct syntax [text](URL). The other issue is that you can either write header using Markdown or you need to separate HTML and Markdown. The following two versions both work fine:
<h5>3. Example plots</h5>

In the comments section, there is a [link][3] to the [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20sin%284%2A%28x%2B1%29%29%2Fsin%28x%2B1%29%20%2B%20sin%284%2A%28x-1%29%29%2Fsin%28x-1%29) of 
$$
y=\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x+1\right)\right)}{x+1}+\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x-1\right)\right)}{x-1}
$$

3. Example plots
In the comments section, there is a link to the plot of
$$
y=\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x+1\right)\right)}{x+1}+\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x-1\right)\right)}{x-1}
$$
(Notice the empty line between the header and the rest of the text.)
##### 3. Example plots #####
In the comments section, there is a [link][3] to the [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20sin%284%2A%28x%2B1%29%29%2Fsin%28x%2B1%29%20%2B%20sin%284%2A%28x-1%29%29%2Fsin%28x-1%29) of 
$$
y=\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x+1\right)\right)}{x+1}+\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x-1\right)\right)}{x-1}
$$

3. Example plots
In the comments section, there is a link to the plot of
$$
y=\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x+1\right)\right)}{x+1}+\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x-1\right)\right)}{x-1}
$$
(In this case the empty line is not needed - since Markdown is used for the header.)

Let me show you the following answer twice (one time in code format and one time for real):
This is a hyperlink: [Link title][1]

  [1]: https://www.hln.be

This is a hyperlink: Link title
